# Ocaml: Exporting a type in an mli file

Tags: ocaml

I have a file context.ml where a map is defined

```
module CtxMap = Map.make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)
```

and a function `map_get` with type `CtxMap.key -> 'a CtxMap.t -> 'a`

How do I add the CtxMap declaration to the context.mli file? 
I can't find a way to do it as mli files can't contain code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
module CtxMap : Map.S with type key = int
```

In the `map.ml` file provided with ocaml, the name of the signature for the functor is `S`, and `key` is the only abstract type you want to expose to the outside modules.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, you can always do:

```
ocamlc -i -c context.ml
```

to output the default `.mli` file to stdout.  The only issue with this (in your case) is that it expands the signature of the map.

Comment: You'll want to add `-c` to avoid adding in all the dependencies --this option compiles, but does not link.